# Terrafom - manager providers.tf for multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, terraform

I am using terraform to manage an Azure subscription (sub1).

I have this file:

cat providers.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 2.25"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.16.8"

  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "my.resource_group"
    storage_account_name = "my.storage_account_name "
    container_name       = "my.container_name"
    key                  = "my.terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

Inside my subscription (sub1) I have the resource group "my.resource_group" where I have my storage account "my.storage_account_name ", container "my.container_name" and where I keep my tfstates.

I want to manage a new subscription (sub2), and maybe do the same thing to keep the tfstates. This is, create a new resource group inside this sub2, a new storage account, a new container and keep the tfstates inside it.

I want to be able to create resources inside sub1 or in sub2, using terraform, and keep the tfstates inside the subscription I am using.

How can I achieve this and how do I have to change my providers.tf file to accomplish this?

Comment: You would add a new 'provider' block with the `alias` property set and with a different subscription_id property

Answer (score 1):

You can create an alias for the desired subscription and then create a reference in the desired resource using a provider reference.

```
# This is the "Default" provider
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.dev_sub_id
  tenant_id       = var.dev_tenant_id
  client_id       = var.dev_client_id
  client_secret   = var.dev_client_secret

  features {}
}

# This provider uses the "prod" alias
provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "prod"

  subscription_id = var.prod_sub_id
  tenant_id       = var.prod_tenant_id
  client_id       = var.prod_client_id
  client_secret   = var.prod_client_secret

  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "dev" {
  name     = "resource-group-dev"
  location = var.location
}
 
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "prod" {
  name     = "resource-group-prod"
  location = var.location
 
  provider = azurerm.prod
}
```